# Small Subgroup confinement Attack Diffie Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman

In small subgroup confinement attack we are taking k (the power which Eve will use to be)

`k = (p-1)/w`

where p-1 is the order of the group on which Alice and Bob is working on (Legit Users) and w is the order of the subgroup.

Is it necessary that w has to be of prime order ?

One of the examples I saw

P = 29
W was taken as 4

So k turned out to be 7

Comment: No <15 char pad>

Comment: Hii can you please explain an bit further

Comment: No, it is not necessary for $w$ to be prime (on stackexchange comments have to be at least 15 characters long which prevents me from just answering "no").

Comment: Ohh okay thanks